# Spring new transaction combined with Retryable

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions, activiti, spring-retry

If I have a method that has a Spring retryable for a certain exception, and also has a Transactional(Requires_new), every time the retry is done, will it create a new transaction or use the existing one?

ie

```
@Retryable(maxAttempts = 5, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 250), include = {ActivitiOptimisticLockingException.class})
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void setVariable(String processId, String variableName, String variableValue){
    engine.getRuntimeService().setVariable(processId, variableName, variableValue);
}
```

What will actually happen here?

Comment: What are your tests results ?

Comment: Please see this reply: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49678581/spring-retry-with-transactional

Answer (score 3):

will be created new transaction each time. 
it the same as get service from spring context and call method N times. every call creates new transaction (use propagation  that you added into service or method). Call your transactioanl servics method call it's call a proxy, retry calls that proxy also. Also your transaction might have timeout,retry try call in new timeout duration ,not N try times in one timeout

Comment: Actually it depends on the order of the interceptors being registered.

Comment: Agree. It's true for default order