# Spring Retry with Transactional

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-retry

Is Spring Retry guaranteed to work with Spring's `@Transactional` annotation?

Specifically, I'm trying to use `@Retryable` for optimistic locking. It seems like it would be dependent on the ordering of the AOP proxies that were created. For example, if the calls look like this:

Calling code -> Retry Proxy -> Transaction Proxy -> Actual DB Code

Then it would work correctly, but if the proxies were structured like this:

Calling code -> Transaction Proxy -> Retry Proxy -> Actual DB Code

Then the retry wouldn't work, because the act of closing the transaction is what throws the optmistic locking exception.

In testing, it appeared to generate the first case (retry, then transaction), but I couldn't tell if this was a guaranteed behavior or just lucky.

Comment: A more interesting question, I think, is if @ Transacional will work with a @ Recover annotated method.... it seems it does not!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Found the answer here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained
Table 2 indicates that the advice for the `Transactional` annotation has an order of `Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE`, which means that it is safe to combine `Retryable` with `Transactional` as long as you aren't overriding the order of the advice for either of those annotations. In other words, you can safely use this form:

```
@Retryable(StaleStateException.class)
@Transactional
public void performDatabaseActions() {
    //Database updates here that may cause an optimistic locking failure 
    //when the transaction closes
}
```

Comment: But, the advice for the `@Retryable` annotation has an order of `Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE` too! Looks like your conclusion (about safety of the usage) is incorrect. If both advices for `@Retryable` and `@Transactional` have the same order, the resulting order is undefined (i.e., can't be trusted). So, to make it reliable it is required to change the order of `@Retryable` advice. There are multiple ways to do this, but starting from `spring-retry` 2.0.1 (not released yet) there is new `order` parameter of `@EnableRetry` annotation.

Answer (score 6):

At the moment (spring-retry version < 2.0.1), by default the order is **undefined** as both advices for `@Retryable` and `@Transactional` annotations have `order = Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE`.

It happens that `RetryConfiguration` advice implements `IntroductionAdvisor` interface. There is also method `org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply` that adds into list all found advisors, but it does it using 2 consecutive loops: at first it adds all advisors that implement `IntroductionAdvisor` interface and then all other avisors (this is why `RetryConfiguration` advisor always happen to be before `BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor` in this list). Then `org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.sort` method is called, but because both advisors have the same order, the method keeps the order of advisors in the list.

So, basically, the reason why `@Retryable` advisor is applied before `@Transactional` advisor at the moment is just "by accident", or "implementation detail". It could be changed any moment by changing implementation of `AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply` method or `AnnotationAwareOrderComparator` etc. So, it's better to not rely on this implementation detail in your code. :)

Starting from `spring-retry` version `2.0.1` (not released yet) there is new `order` attribute of `@EnableRetry` annotation that is equal to `Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE - 1` by default to make sure `@Retryable` advice will always be ordered before `@Transactional` advice (when `@Transactional` advice order is default).

The `order` attribute could also be set to any other value, according to your needs, e.g. `Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE - 4`.

```
@EnableRetry(order = Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE - 4)
@Configuration
public class MyAppConfiguration {}
```

With this configuration (and starting from spring-retry 2.0.1 - by default) the order of applying advices will be as this:

```
@Retryable
  @Transactional
    Your method body
  End of @Transactional
End of @Retryable
```

Answer (score 5):

By default Spring Retry builds advice with the same LOWEST_PRECEDENCE order - take a look at the RetryConfiguration.
However, there is a pretty simple way to override this order:

```
@Configuration
public class MyRetryConfiguration extends RetryConfiguration {
   @Override
   public int getOrder() {
      return Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
   }
}
```

Make sure to omit the @EnableRetry annotation to avoid default RetryConfiguration be taken into account.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to test it independenty and be sure how it behaves then you may have @Transactional @Service, then another service that uses transaction one and just adds retries.

In this case, no matter how much you test you are relying on undocumented behaviour (how exactly annotations processing is ordered). This may change between minor releases, based on order in which independent Spring beans are created, etc etc. In short, you are asking for problems when you mix @Transactional and @Retry on same method.

edit: There is similar answered question https://stackoverflow.com/a/45514794/1849837 with code

```
@Retryable(StaleStateException.class)
@Transactional
public void doSomethingWithFoo(Long fooId){
    // read your entity again before changes!
    Foo foo = fooRepository.findOne(fooId);
    foo.setStatus(REJECTED)  // <- sample foo modification
} // commit on method end
```

In that case it seems to be fine, because no matter what order is (retry then transaction, or transaction or retry) observable behaviour will be the same.

Comment: That's roughly the code that I was testing with, but wouldn't the behavior be different if the two proxies are reversed? I thought that `Retryable` essentially creates a try/catch (i.e. "around" advice). So if the transaction is closed OUTSIDE that try/catch, the exception wouldn't be caught by the retry proxy. (Maybe I'm just not understanding how Spring Retry works behind the scenes...)

Answer (score 3):

In case you are using Spring Boot and you want to use `@Retryable`, this is what you need to do:

1. Add the dependency to the pom:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

2. Enable retries in your Spring Boot application:

```java
@EnableRetry // <-- Add This
@SpringBootApplication
public class SomeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SomeApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

3. Annotate your method with `@Retryable`:

```java
@Retryable(value = CannotAcquireLockException.class,
        backoff = @Backoff(delay = 100, maxDelay = 300))
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public boolean someMethod(String someArg, long otherArg) {
    ...
}
```

You can annotate the same method with both `@Retryable` and `@Transactional` and it will work as expected.