# Using `@Transactional` with Spring's `@Retriable`

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-transactions

I'm using spring data jpa with `@EnableJpaRepositories` and spring retry with `@EnableRetry`.

I want to retry a transactional method that calls another transactional method that acquires an Oracle `DBMS_LOCK` using a wrapper stored proc: `MY_PROC_THAT_CALLS_ORACLE_DBMS_LOCK`.

The lock acquired is set up to be released upon transaction commit and that is what I want.

But despite successfully acquiring the lock on, say, the second attempt, my transaction is getting marked as `rollback_only` and is failing.

I suspect the `@Transactional` annotation on my `acquireDbmsLock` method in my Repository is seeing the `SQLException` and setting the transaction to roll back only.

From my understanding of the transaction propogation semantics, I think I don't want `@Transactional(propogation = Propogation.REQUIRES_NEW)` on the `acquireDbmsLock` interface method. Looks like Hibernate doesn't support `Propogation.NESTED`.

So, what is a good solution for this problem?

I'm resisting setting `noRollbackFor = SQLException.class`.

Here's my code:

```java
@Retriable(SQLException.class)
@Transactional
public MyThing myService(String thingId) {
  MyThing myThing = myRepository.findMyThing(thingId);

  if(myThing == null) {
    myLockRepository.acquireDbmsLock(thingId);
    myRepository.createMyThing(thingId);
  } else {
    return myThing;
  }
}
```

```java
public interface MyLockRepository extends Repository<XXX, YY> {

  @Procedure(procedureName = "MY_PROC_THAT_CALLS_ORACLE_DBMS_LOCK")
  void acquireDbmsLock(String lockName);
}
```

I've tried overriding the default retry configuration as shown below as well (after removing the `@EnableRetry` annotation):

```java
@Bean
  RetryConfiguration retryConfiguration() {
    // Need retries to happen before transaction is set to rollback only: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53654301/499635
    return new RetryConfiguration() {
      @Override
      public int getOrder() {
       return Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
      }
    };
  }
```

Comment: Actually, setting `noRollbackFor` on `acquireDbmsLock`'s `@Transactional` didn't help either. The transaction is still being marked as `rollback-only`.

Comment: I'm reading that methods other than the CRUD methods aren't transactional, but my transactions are still getting marked `rollback-only` despite me taking off the `@Transactional` on the `acquireDbmsLock` method. How do I force a spring-data-jpa generated method to be non tranasctional?